# How does a gas lamp mantle work? Is it just black body radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Old gas lighting often involved a thing called a "mantle" which was a cloth mesh coated with thorium dioxide.  The gas flame heated the mantle and the mantle gave off the indoor lighting that people used before electricity.

My question is - was there something special about a thorium dioxide mantle, or is it just a good black body radiator?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_mantle#Mechanism

Comment: Wire mesh? All the mantles I've seen were made of cloth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gas light mantles have metal oxides mixed into them which, when heated, produce a line spectrum in the visible range that has enough R/G/B content to furnish a light that is white or nearly so to the human eye.

Thorium is one such metal; calcium is another. Before electric lights came into existence, stage lighting ("footlight") was done with a gas flame that heated a solid block of calcium oxide, which produced a bright yellowish light. As calcium oxide was called lime, these were called *limelights*.

See Paul Young's comments below for more insights.

Comment: you may also wish to add:  this is specifically NOT the case of a black body radiator ... 1) the flame is not in thermal equilibrium and there is a phenomenon called candoluminescence .. 2) the thorium, calcium, etc... is particularly not emissive in the IR - definitely not a black body   .... tks